# No monad in Python?

Tags: python

Please help understand why set(first).update(second) does not work in Python.

```
>>> names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
>>> names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
>>> 
>>> sn1=set(names1)
>>> sn1.update(names2)
>>> sn1
{'Sophia', 'Emma', 'Ava', 'Olivia'}

>>> sn1=set(names1).update(names2)
>>> sn1
(Nothing displayed)
```

## Update

As in the comment, it had nothing to do with monad. The question was if there was a way to get the result of chained transformations on a object in one line.

Comment: It *does* work. It just doesn't return anything.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with monads, either.

Comment: You have sn1=set(names1).update(names2). Did you mean sn1.set(names1).update(names2) ?

Comment: No, the OP did not mean that.

Comment: update probably returns None.

Comment: `update` absolutely returns `None`, as demonstrated in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, `sn1` is set to the return value of the `update` method (which is `None`), not the set returned by `set(names1)`.

Starting in Python 3.8, you can do something like you are trying using assignment expressions.

```
>>> names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
>>> names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
>>> (sn1 := set(names1)).update(names2)
>>> sn1
{'Sophia', 'Olivia', 'Emma', 'Ava'}
```

Comment: The assignment expression is a little bit misleading: If `update` fails, `sn1` is still the original set. `sn1 = set(names1) | set(names2)` is much clearer and in the spirit of what one would use in a functional language.

Comment: It's just a variation on chaining that could do what the OP expected ordinary chaining to accomplish.